# Does $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+1)!}\left(\prod_{l=0}^{k}\left(1-ls\right)\right) x^{k+1}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, divergent-series

Does

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+1)!}\left(\prod_{l=0}^{k}\left(1-ls\right)\right) x^{k+1}$$

converge for $s\in(0,1)$? If so, to what value?

Comment: Why the -1? Just out of being mean?

Comment: To the downvoter: Downvoting is NOT for punishing a question for absence of effort. That’s what voting to close is for. Downvoting means you don’t think the question is of any use or interest.

Comment: For $|x|<1$ the sequence converges for any $s\in(0,1)$. Are you asking whether the sequence converges for ALL $x$ whenever $s\in(0,1)$ ?

Comment: Angela: Yes! And ideally to what value... I actually need it for a practical application!

Comment: Could you share what the practical application is?

Comment: A stochastic optimal controller for linear thresholded systems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, if $ s\neq 0 $ then the sum will converge if and only if $\left|sx\right|<1 $, and if $ s=0 $ then it will converge for any real $ x \cdot $

Let $ \left(s,x\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{*}\times\mathbb{R} $, such that $ sx\in\left]-1,1\right[ $, Doing a simple change of index, gives : \begin{aligned} \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{\left(k+1\right)!}\prod_{\ell =0}^{k}{\left(1-\ell s\right)}x^{k+1}}=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{k!}\prod_{\ell =0}^{k-1}{\left(1-\ell s\right)}x^{k}}&=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}{\frac{1}{k!}\prod_{\ell =0}^{k-1}{\left(\frac{1}{s}-\ell\right)}\left(sx\right)^{k}}\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}{\binom{\frac{1}{s}}{k}\left(sx\right)^{k}} \end{aligned}

Where $ \binom{\alpha}{n} $ designates, for any $ \left(\alpha,n\right)\in\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{N} $, the product $ \frac{\alpha\left(\alpha -1\right)\cdots\left(\alpha -n+1\right)}{n!} \cdot $

The final result would, then, be : $$ \left(1+sx\right)^{\frac{1}{s}}-1 $$

If $ s=0 $, then, as we said, the sum will converge for all $ x\in\mathbb{R} $ to : $$ \exp{x}-1 $$

Comment: It also converges if $s=0$.

Comment: True, I'll fix it. but the formula I gave won't hold in that case.

Comment: Well, you can do it as a special case: it gives $e^x-1$.

Comment: Well @J.G. I did.

Comment: I verified it numerically! Seems to work perfectly, even outside $\left|sx\right|<1 $.

Comment: There's [a way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsallis_statistics#q-exponential) to unify the $s=0$ case with the $s\ne0$ case.

Comment: It solved my problem perfectly!